# InAppBrowser Events handling issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I am working on mobile app using:

- Ionic 2.1.4
- Cordova 6.4.0
- Angular 1.5.3

I've one view with external url using [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) plugin and I have a link in this website should redirect to certain view in my app

this issue is `$location.url()` not redirecting and not working at all, but when I tested the event I found it trigger normally.

here is my full code

```
angular.module('yogipass').controller('iframe',function ($location) {
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log('here');

  var ref=cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://192.168.42.218/index.html', '_blank', 'location=no');

  ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
   if (event.url.match("mobile/login")) {
    console.log('worked!') // this logged normally
    $location.url('/login');

      ref.close();
   }
  });




}

])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run digest cycle manually as you are changing `location` path from asynchronous event which is outside angular context.

Do wrap you code in `$timeout` function, which will fire up digest cycle. Apparently that will help to update location.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $location.url('/login');
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: @PeterWilson Glad to help you, Thanks :)